# Function not searching for a specific word

Tags: php, mysql, search

This is quite weird but my search function can search for any word except the word "grinder" from my item table. I have tried everything but it does not seem to search for that word. Can anyone help me please?

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX item_name_other_name_desc_index 
    ON item (name,other_name,description) 

public static function Search($string) 
{    

    $delims = ',.; '; 
        $word = strtok($string,$delims); 
        while($word) 
        { 

           $result['accepted'][] = $word;                    
           $word = strtok($delims); 

        } 

          $string = implode(" ", $result['accepted']); 

    $sql = 'SELECT item_id,name,other_name,description,price,discounted_price, thumbnail_photo,large_photo 
    FROM item 
    WHERE  
    MATCH(name,other_name,description) 
    AGAINST(:string)' ; 
    $parameters = array(':string' => $string); 
    $result['items'] = DB::GetAll($sql,$parameters); 
    return $result; 
}
```

The names of the items:
9 In 15 AMP Motor Angle Grinder 
8 In Bench Grinder 
1/4 In Angle Die Grinder 
7 In Angle Grinder 
3 In Straight Grinder 
Ryobi HP512K cordless drill/driver kit 
6-Pack Spray Paint 
Non-Contact Voltage Tester

When I change the above to : 
9 In 15 AMP Motor Angle Grinder 
8 In Bench Grind 
1/4 In Angle Die Grind 
7 In Angle Grind 
3 In Straight Grind 
Ryobi HP512K cordless drill/driver kit 
6-Pack Spray Paint 
Non-Contact Voltage Tester

and I search for Grinder, the record => 9 In 15 AMP Motor Angle Grinder is being displayed.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data in item?

Comment: Can you show an example record?

Comment: I think I have found the problem. I have 7 items in my table Item.
5 of them have the name Grinder. When i search for Grinder, it displays no result. When i changed 4 of the item named Grinder to Grind, then i search for Grinder, it displays the item Grinder..
Im confused!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, mysql fulltext search treats a word that occurs in more than 50% or the rows as a stopword ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-natural-language.html ). Try searching in boolean mode ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html ), where you don't have 50% threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Does it make any different if the word Grinder is moved within the text, so "15 AMP Motor Angle Grinder" would be "15 AMP Motor Angle Grinder Test"? I ask this because Grinder is always the last work of the name.

I'm not an expert on full text searching, but this is where I would start.